# Why does my insert not filter out null values?

Tags: sql, t-sql, etl, data-warehouse

I'm trying to implement SCD2 by using `INSERT` and `UPDATE` instead of using MERGE. I need to insert new rows from my source table into my target table if the id doesn't exist and at the same time make sure that the column row `compositekey` is not null without crashing the insertion. At the moment I get this result when I run the select query:

Output:

| ID | namn | hash | compositekey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | demo | 222 | null |
| 2 | demo2 | 22220 | 212 |
| 3 | demo3 | 22220 | null |
| 4 | demo2 | 22220 | 434 |

Expected output:

| ID | namn | hash | compositekey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | demo2 | 22220 | 212 |
| 4 | demo2 | 22220 | 434 |

Query:

```sql
Insert into target
SELECT s.ID, s.namn, s.hash, s.compositekey
FROM source s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select id, compositekey  from target  where id = s.id and compositekey is null and s.compositekey is null)
```

I'm expecting the query to filter out and only give me rows that do not exist in my target table based on the id and composite key that is not null from the source table. I suspect that I'm querying wrong in the "is null" part.

Comment: What is the object aliased as `s` in your query? You only define the alias `a` for `source`.

Comment: `select s.id, ... from source a ...` - is this just a typo? What means condition `and s.compositekey is null` in inner query? This checks just outer composite key value.

Comment: Yea it was a typo my bad..

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on TARGET table contents.
if "compositekey is null" is not True, so the INSERT will insert the compositekey with NULL values.

Try this way (The Where should be with UNIQUE columns on TARGET tables):

insert into target
SELECT s.ID, s.namn, s.hash, s.compositekey
FROM source s
where (s.ID, s.compositekey) NOT IN
(select id, compositekey  from target )
;